# Chart.js - Line charts with different colors for each border lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

As per chart.js [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) I can specify an Array for Colors of border and background.

However on using this following configuration for chart.js. I am trying to figure out why array values for `borderColor` and `backgroundColor` are not working.

I am using chart.js 2.6.0 via react-chartjs-2. Is this not something which is supported out of the box with chart.js v2 ?

```
"{
 "type": "Line",
 "labels": [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday"
 ],
 "datasets": [
  {
   "label": "Page Views (This Week)",
   "fill": false,
   "lineTension": 0.1,
   "backgroundColor": [
    "rgba(75,192,192, 0.4)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 0.4)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 0.4)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 0.4)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 0.4)"
   ],
   "borderColor": [
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)"
   ],
   "borderCapStyle": "butt",
   "borderDash": [],
   "borderDashOffset": 0,
   "borderJoinStyle": "miter",
   "pointBorderColor": [
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(75,192,192, 1)"
   ],
   "pointBackgroundColor": "#fff",
   "pointBorderWidth": 1,
   "pointHoverRadius": 5,
   "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "rgba(75,192,192, 1)",
   "pointHoverBorderColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   "pointHoverBorderWidth": 2,
   "pointRadius": 1,
   "pointHitRadius": 10,
   "data": [
    19615,
    37337,
    54307,
    70944,
    87444
   ]
  },
  {
   "label": "Page Views (Last Week)",
   "fill": false,
   "lineTension": 0.1,
   "backgroundColor": [
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 0.4)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 0.4)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 0.4)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 0.4)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 0.4)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 0.4)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 0.4)"
   ],
   "borderColor": [
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)"
   ],
   "borderCapStyle": "butt",
   "borderDash": [],
   "borderDashOffset": 0,
   "borderJoinStyle": "miter",
   "pointBorderColor": [
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
    "rgba(1, 223, 111, 1)",
    "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)"
   ],
   "pointBackgroundColor": "#fff",
   "pointBorderWidth": 1,
   "pointHoverRadius": 5,
   "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "rgba(242, 169, 12, 1)",
   "pointHoverBorderColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   "pointHoverBorderWidth": 2,
   "pointRadius": 1,
   "pointHitRadius": 10,
   "data": [
    17819,
    35785,
    52761,
    69470,
    84987,
    104958,
    125497
   ]
  }
 ]
}"
```

Generated graph looks like this, I was expected alternating line segments to have alternate colors.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use two datasets.

Then for the second dataset, you can do something like this:

```
borderColor: [null, #fff]
```

On the third dataset, you would add two `null`'s and etc.

Source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2430